# How to compare all elements of a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

This code in under is will let the user enter the number of elements of list and the user need enter the elements ( User will need type number_of_elements_of_list times) and then count how many positive number, negative number, zero number. The code is like this:

```
    the_number_of_elements_of_the_list = int(input())
    number_list = []
    for i in range(1, the_number_of_elements_of_the_list + 1):
        number_list.append(int(input()))
    positive_number_count = 0
    negative_number_count = 0
    zero_number_count = 0
    if number_list == 0:
        zero_number_count += 1
    elif number_list == 1 or number_list > 1:
        positive_number_count += 1
    elif number_list < 0:
        negative_number_count += 1
    print(positive_number_count, negative_number_count, zero_number_count)
```

The code have a problem: The list can not compare like that. It will be error but i don't know how to compare the elements of list. Can you help me solve this problem?

Comment: Firstly I smell homework. Now two things. You need to indent the block that you want the for loop to run. Second you want to do your zero initialisation of variable before the loop

Comment: @teambob Oh thanks for tell me about the unident block one but i don't understand about the final answer.

Comment: You'll need to initialise your counter variables outside the for loop. But that's the least of your worries. Try running your code and input some non-integer values and see what happens

Comment: @DarkKnight I enter the first output is -1 and it print a error: TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'list' of 'int' ( The project stop at line 10)

Comment: What did you expect to happen when you tried to compare an int with a list?

Comment: @DarkKnight It will error when compare an int with a list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, as teambob pointed out, add indent to the for-loop block.

Secondly, as DarkKnight pointed out, put the count variables outside the for-loop.

Thirdly, for each iteration, in order to use that value alone, use `number_list[i-1]` instead of `number_list`. (The index is `i-1` rather than `i` because the range in your code starts from 1 rather than 0)

The final code would look like:

```
the_number_of_elements_of_the_list = int(input())
positive_number_count = 0
negative_number_count = 0
zero_number_count = 0
number_list = []
for i in range(1, the_number_of_elements_of_the_list + 1):
    number_list.append(int(input()))
    if number_list[i-1] == 0:
        zero_number_count += 1
    elif number_list[i-1] == 1 or number_list[i-1] > 1:
        positive_number_count += 1
    elif number_list[i-1] < 0:
        negative_number_count += 1
print(positive_number_count, negative_number_count, zero_number_count)
```